# How do I get assets to compile to their own files AND into the application.js file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, asset-pipeline

Alright so lets say I have these files in `vendor/assets/javascript/`:

- `modernizer.js`
- `lightbox.js`
- `highchart.js`

And these files in `app/assets/javascript/`:

- `pages.js.coffee`
- `accounts.js.coffee`
- `application.js.coffee`
- `charts.js.coffee`

I would like to have `lightbox.js`, `highchart.js` and `modernizer.js` all compiled into seperate files. Here's an example in `public/assets/`:

- `application-HASH.js`
- `modernizer-HASH.js`
- `highchart-HASH.js`
- `lightbox-HASH.js`

I'm using Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.3 (Not that this matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to the list of assets to precompile by sticking this in application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += ['lightbox.js', 'highchart.js', 'modernizer.js']
```

Comment: I tried that a while ago with little success, I'll give it a shot and then mark this correct if it works. In the meantime, how about if I want to do the same with `pages.js.coffee`? Or any amount of files I don't want loaded on EVERY page? :/

Comment: I think that should be fine. If it doesn't you might need to add a separate 'manifest' file that requires the various .coffee files and add that file to `config.assets.precompile`

Comment: Looking at the git history it looks like I typoed the name of the file which is why it didn't work. It's definitely working now!